# Edit text according to select input

Tags: vue.js

I'm developing an RFQ interface for an OTC desk. I try to return price for a specific cryptocurrency that is selected with `<v-select>`, I'm trying to send a `GET` request to price endpoint for selected cryptocurrency.

For example, if cryptocurrency is `BTC` I want the client to send a `GET` request to `api.endpoint/price/BTCUSDT`.

Select input:

```
<v-select
 v-model="yousendselect"
 :items="itemsYouSend"
 :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
 label="You send"
 required
></v-select>
```

Items (cryptocurrencies):

```
      item: [
        'Bitcoin',
        'Ethereum',
        'Litecoin',
        'Ripple',
      ],
```

```
Bitcoin => BTCUSDT
Ethereum => ETHUSDT
Litecoin => LTCUSDT
Ripple => XRPUSDT
```

I find some sources that can help to send a `GET` request but I didn't figure how to send `GET` request to endpoint depending on select input.

Where price is going to take place is:

```
<v-text-field
 v-model="yougetamount"
 label="{{ price }}"
 type="number"
 name="yougetamount"
 required
></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can watch on your property `yousendselect`:

```
watch: {
yousendselect(value){
// check and make your request

}
}
```